# Eigenvalues of general $2\times2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am wondering what the expression is for eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ matrix in general form

$$A=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}
\right]$$

I tried to compute $|A-\lambda I| = 0$ but it got very messy.

Comment: Eigenvalue problems are generally messy. You should expect it although I'm not sure a quadradic equation qualifies.

Comment: If you think this one is messy, try $3 \times 3$ or $4 \times 4$.

Comment: You could at least show what you've got and where exactly are you stuck in the calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2 - t \lambda + d$ where $t = a_{11} + a_{12}$ is the trace and $d = a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}$ the determinant of $A$.
The eigenvalues are the roots of this quadratic, namely
$$ \frac{t \pm \sqrt{t^2-4d}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would throw in the 3 by 3 case, which is worth remembering:

The eigenvalues are the roots of
$$   \lambda^3 - T \lambda^2 + P \lambda - D $$
where trace
$$T = a_{11} +a_{22} +a_{22} $$
and the sum of the two by two principal minors is
$$  P = \left( a_{11} a_{22} -  a_{12} a_{21} \right) +  \left( a_{22} a_{33} -  a_{23} a_{32} \right) +  \left( a_{11} a_{33} -  a_{13} a_{31} \right) $$

Finally the determinant $D$ is given by the "Rule of Sarrus" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus which is also worth memorizing

The point is that it is not necessary to write out the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ every time. My suggestion is to memorize the coefficients of $\det \lambda I - A$  as sums of certain little determinants. If nothing else, it reduces errors by hand.